# Does the Helm of the Dominator synergize with Gorgons Multi-Shot?

Tags: dota

If I'm playing the Gorgon and purchase for her a Helm of the Dominator, does the lifesteal apply to all three of my multishot arrows or just one of them?

Kudos if you can explain how multishot does or does not work with any orb or buff placer effect period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: http://www.playdota.com/guides/instilling-paralyzing-fear

According to this guide apparently her split shot carries orb or buff placer effects only to the main target of the split shot. So, while there isnt 100% synergy, they still work.

Comment: Useful link that happens to be the same, but that guide is a good bit out of date, Medusa's been nerfed a bunch since then.

Comment: @Decency im looking back and forth here and seeing the same numbers, can you specify?

Comment: @Decency or are you saying that BOTH guides are out of date?

Comment: Split Shot happens to be the same in this case, but your link is for v6.68b, which is a while ago. Medusa has been changed since then in other aspects, but it's still the same for Split Shot. The link I gave will always be updated to the most recent patch.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.playdota.com/heroes/gorgon

the official information for the newest dota version (6.73c):

only the maintarget gets applied with orbeffects.

medusas splitshot works like a spell. the additional arrows get "casted" but do physical damage thats why they are not getting any orbeffects.
its comparable to lunas moon glaives.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dotastrategy.com/hero-38-MedusaTheGorgon.html)'s the updated version of Medusa.

• Only the primary target will receive attack effects like bash and orb effects.

Comment: the data on that guide is the same on the one I already mentioned.